# tee /dev/null consuming input?

Tags: unix, pipe, stdout, tee

Somehow it seems as though running `./program | tee /dev/null` is consuming its output. When run on its own, the program prints some text, then continues running while communicating over UDP sockets. It produces a lot of log messages that I wanted to view in a filtered way, so I tried running `./program | grep -v "I dont wan't to see logs like this!" | tail -f` but it produced no output. I gave up a bit and decided to just `tee` the output to another file which I could then inspect with my editor, but it resulted in an empty file.

The program in question was written by a student and so the problem may be within it. What could cause this behaviour? How can I correct it?

Summary:

`./program` prints `output` but `./program | tee /dev/null` doesn't print anything. Problem possibly within source of `./program`, but how to use it properly anyways?

Comment: Perhaps the program detects whether stdout is redirected or not?  Or perhaps it tries to change the file descriptor of the stdout handle?  Do you have the source for the program?

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens when the program in question checks to see if it is conncted to a terminal and does something different for terminal vs non-terminal.  The easiest way to get around this and capture the output anyways is to use script:

```
script -c "./program" /dev/stdout | grep -v "I dont wan't to see logs like this!" | tail -f
```

`script` will run the program in a pseudo-terminal (so it will think it is connected to a terminal) and and write the output to `/dev/stdout` which is then piped to `grep`.

You might also want the `-f` argument to `script` to make it flush output after every write (otherwise things will get buffered before writing to the pipe).

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it didn't work, but it helped me figure out the real problem. For some reason the source contains the code: `if (!fork()) { ... }` with no else... so its running in a fork which I think is what is causing the problem. Anyways, removing the pointless fork fixed it.

Comment: Nevermind, I thought it had fixed it, but it was only dumping the output once I ^C'ed the program. Similar results with your `script` solution, it printed and tee'd correctly, but would not update live. Live updates still only happen if the program is called without any pipes. I even added fflush(stdout)'s throughout to help... no avail.

Comment: If you want it to update live rather than when the program terminates, you'll need to use the `-f` option to script I mentioned above...